# how can we make sure 2 arguments passed are treated as first and third, whereas, the second ad the fourth are taken as defaults

Tags: c++, function

C++ question:
suppose there is a function with following prototype: 
void f(int=10, int=20, int=30,int=40) 
if this function is called by passing 2 arguments to it, how can we make sure these arguments are treated as first and third, whereas, the second ad the fourth are taken as defaults.

I have an idea of resolving this problem using function overloading but I wanna know if there is any direct way of solving this problem?? I am looking for an answer related to c++

Comment: There is no direct way, only work-arounds. Overloading is the way to go here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution with overloading would look like this:

```
void f(int a, int b, int c, int d=40)
{
  // ...
}

void f(int a=10, int c=30)
{
  f(a,20,c);
}
```

I don't think any other solution/work-around would be easier. There are libraries to provide named parameters, but they change the way you call the function and impose quite some overhead at least to the compiler if not to the generated code itself.

Comment: thanx I think I have got what i have been looking for.